# Google Firestore Save User Input Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've been having this issue for a while. I have 3 inputEditTexts that ask the user to input their first name, last name, and their ID. I wanted to save this information into google firestore. I have set up all the dependencies and I know I have it properly connected to google firebase. The issue I find is that every tutorial on this topic is different from one another, and every one I could find does not function 100%. Is there a way to save these 3 values into google firestore **in kotlin** and a way to retrieve these values in another activity?

Comment: Hi Abrahim, it's recommended, when asking a question, to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), any existing code, and/or any links to research you've already done.

Comment: This is covered in the official docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been having this issue for a while. I have 3 inputEditTexts that ask the user to input their first name, last name, and their ID.

To get the data from these EditText objects, please use the following lines of code:

```
val firstName =  firstNameEditText.text.toString().trim()
val lastName =  lastNameEditText.text.toString().trim()
val id =  idEditText.text.toString().trim()
```

> I wanted to save this information into Firestore.

To save the data in Firestore, the most simple solution would be to create a data class:

```
data class User(
    var firstName: String? = null,
    var lastName: String? = null,
    var id: String? = null
)
```

Create an object of the class:

```
val user = User(firstName, lastName, id)
```

And write it to Firestore:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")
usersRef.document(id).set(user).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */)
```

Which will produce the following database schema:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- $id
            |
            --- firstName: "Abrahim"
            |
            --- lastName: "Mahmud"
            |
            --- id: "userIdIntroducedFromKeyboard"
```

To read the data back, simply make a get() call and attach a listener as shown below:

```
val uidRef = usersRef.document(id)
uidRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { doc ->
    if (doc != null) {
        val user = doc.toObject(User::class.java)
        Log.d(TAG, "{$user.firstName} {$user.lastName}")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
    }
}.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
}
```

And the result in the logcat will be:

```
Abrahim Mahmud
```